AWS Batch Python job with multiprocessing intermittently produces empty reports
Environment:

AWS Batch
Python 3.x
boto3 for AWS SDK
DynamoDB for data storage
Multiprocessing with 'fork' context

Key Points:

The issue occurs in AWS Batch, but not consistently - sometime generate report but sometime generates the empty report.
When run locally WITHOUT multiprocessing, the script always succeeds for the same date range.
The AWS Batch job uses multiprocessing with the 'fork' context.

Issue:
In the AWS Batch environment with multiprocessing, the script occasionally produces empty reports. The same script run locally without multiprocessing always succeeds.
Relevant code snippet:
def _f(batch):
    process_id = multiprocessing.current_process().pid
    print(f'Start Process ID: {process_id}, date range: {batch[2]}')
    partner_tag = batch[0]
    loan_type = batch[1]
    dates = batch[2]
    partner_loan_type_tag = partner_tag + '_' + loan_type
    csv_files = []
    done = False
    start_key = None
    i = 0
    total_loans = 0
    while not done:
        i +=  1
        if start_key:
            disbursement_range_loans_temp = partner_loan_table.query(
                IndexName="partner_loan_type_tag-disbursement_date-index",
                ProjectionExpression=projection_item_string,
                KeyConditionExpression=Key('partner_loan_type_tag').eq(partner_loan_type_tag) & Key(
                    'disbursement_date').between(dates[0], dates[1]),
                ExclusiveStartKey=start_key
            )

        else:
            disbursement_range_loans_temp = partner_loan_table.query(
                IndexName="partner_loan_type_tag-disbursement_date-index",
                ProjectionExpression=projection_item_string,
                KeyConditionExpression=Key('partner_loan_type_tag').eq(
                    partner_loan_type_tag) & Key('disbursement_date').between(dates[0], dates[1])
            )
        disbursement_range_loan_items = disbursement_range_loans_temp.get('Items', [
        ])
        total_loans += len(disbursement_range_loan_items)
        df = pd.json_normalize(disbursement_range_loan_items, sep='*')
        if not df.empty:
            process = multiprocessing.current_process()
            csv_name=str(process.pid)+'_'+str(dates[0])+'_'+str(dates[1])+'_'+str(i)+'.csv'
            df.to_csv(csv_name, index=False)

        start_key = disbursement_range_loans_temp.get(
            'LastEvaluatedKey', None)
        done = start_key is None
    print(f'END Process ID: {process_id}, date range: {batch[2]},total loans: {total_loans}')
    return


with multiprocessing.get_context("fork").Pool(processes=num_processes) as pool:
     pool.map(_f, batch)

then i merge all the csv file created by the function(_f) to get the final report
What I've tried:

Verified data exists in DynamoDB for the given date range
Checked for DynamoDB throttling or capacity issues(database works on demand)
Verified AWS credentials and permissions
Tested locally without multiprocessing (always succeeds)

